# C# - Plot a Virtual Rectangle(4 Co-ordinates),on a Virtual Graph (map of the earth), and Search if another co-ordinate exists in the Rectangle

Tags: c#, google-maps, plot, graph

Am using google map API to get a [rectangle](https://jsfiddle.net/mckabue/ezejh6ch/1/) like this
[image: p]

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                if (place && place.geometry) {
                    var ne = place.geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
                    var sw = place.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();

                    var _ne = { lat: ne.lat(), lng: ne.lng() };
                    var _nw = { lat: ne.lat(), lng: sw.lng() };
                    var _sw = { lat: sw.lat(), lng: sw.lng() };
                    var _se = { lat: sw.lat(), lng: ne.lng() };
            });
```

From that, i get what seems like a rectangle of the area i searched. From that i want to search if another point (latitude and longitude) exists.
 From what i imagine, i want to be able to create a virtual rectangle, plot it on a virtual graph of the map of the earth, and check if the point is on the rectangle. I also want to be able to get from the map, how far the point is from another point or from the [rectangle](https://jsfiddle.net/mckabue/ezejh6ch/1/).

**NB: This should not need to render the rectangle or the graph, a C# extension method will do just fine**

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't a solution to my problem, but for now, i can continue with the following little solution.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Is in the geo rectable.
        /// http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool InGeoRectable(string point, string[] rectangle, double distance = 0)
        {
            double rectangleDiagonal = 0;

            if (!rectangle.Any())
                return false;


            try
            {
                var enumerator = rectangle.GetEnumerator();
                enumerator.MoveNext();
                GeoCoordinate rectangleConner = (enumerator.Current as string).ToCoordinate();
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    double _distance = (enumerator.Current as string).ToCoordinate().GetDistanceTo(rectangleConner);
                    if (_distance > rectangleDiagonal)
                        rectangleDiagonal = _distance;
                }


                return !rectangle.Any(r => r.ToCoordinate().GetDistanceTo(point.ToCoordinate()) > (rectangleDiagonal + distance));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

and using [System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808858(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static GeoCoordinate ToCoordinate(this string point)
        {
            string[] latLang = point.Split(',');
            double _latitude = -91;
            double _longitude = -181;

            if (Double.TryParse(latLang[0].Trim(), out _latitude) && Double.TryParse(latLang[1].Trim(), out _longitude))
            {
                if (!Double.NaN.Equals(_latitude) && !Double.NaN.Equals(_longitude))
                {
                    if ((_latitude >= -90 || _latitude <= 90) && (_longitude >= -180 || _longitude <= 180))
                    {
                        return new GeoCoordinate(_latitude, _longitude);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new GeoCoordinate(_latitude, _longitude);

        }
```

now i can call that with a list of points making up a rectangle, and the point i want to search:

```
"-1.165677,37.105044099999986"
"-1.4522759,36.65112709999994"
"-1.165677,36.65112709999994"
"-1.4522759,37.105044099999986"
```

and `"-1.2882998,36.8737025"`

ITS WORKING, WHICH IS WHAT I NEEDED, BUT I REQUIRE A FASTER AND A MORE FEASIBLE SOLUTION